# Two tables addition in one array with mysql_query

Tags: mysql, arrays

I got two tables in mysql lets call them lipids and adduct:

lipids:

```
    ID  |  name  |  mz  |  hg  |
    1   |  36:2  |  785 |  PC  |
    2   |  36:1  |  803 |  PT  |
    3   |  36:2  |  804 |  PS  |
```

adduct:

```
    ID  |  name  |  mz     |  charge   |
    1   |  +H+   |  1.     |  1        |
    2   |  -H+   |  -1.    |  -1       |
```

Okay i will need to make a search for 36:2, but i will need all information given, plus i will need the adduct table added to the mz. So i will need to get an array like:

```
    [ID] => 1
    [name] => 36:2
    [hg] => PC
    [mz] => 785
    [mz +H+]=>786
    [charge +H+] =>1
    [mz-H+] =>784
    [charge -H+] =>-1

    [ID] => 3
    [name] => 36:2
    [hg] => PS
    [mz] => 804
    [mz +H+]=>805
    [charge +H+] =>1
    [mz-H+] =>803
    [charge -H+] =>-1
```

EDIT:

I am using a website to get the results from the mysql database... so i am using this php codes.. to get some of the results.

```
if(preg_match('/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/',$name))
{
 if(!$head)
   {
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM lipids where name='$name'");
   }

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
     {
       print_r($row);            
    }
```

//$name = This is a variable, which will a user will input from a input field.

There will be multiple answeres to oen input. So the list of answeres will be big. The tables above is just a quick overview, as they will have more data.

Comment: How are the two tables related? i.e. how do we know which row in `adduct` relates to each row in `lipids`?

Comment: Also - will there *always* be two related rows in `adduct` (however they're related)? If there are more - or less - then how should the output look?

Comment: They are not directly related... I am thinking of getting an array inside an array. So the first will do the mysql_query(select * from lipids where name ='36:2') then the other will have to do (select * from adduct) then an echo or something to get the right information out, i am not quite sure how to do that. The output should like the one i have wrotten with the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the contents of adduct is fixed at 2 rows then something like this maybe:-

```
SELECT a.ID, a.name, a.hg, a.mz, a.mz+b.mz AS 'mz +H+', b.mz AS 'charge +H+', a.mz+c.mz AS 'mz -H+', c.mz AS 'charge -H+'
FROM lipids a
LEFT JOIN adduct b ON b.name = '+H+'
LEFT JOIN adduct b ON b.name = '-H+'
```

But I have no idea if you will land up with many +H+ rows on adduct (for example)

EDIT

You can just do a join and get one row for each mz name and charge, then sort it out in code afterwards (easy is most languages):-

```
SELECT a.ID, a.name, a.hg, a.mz, b.name, a.mz+b.mz, b.mz
FROM lipids a
CROSS JOIN adduct b 
WHERE a.name='36:2'
```

You can also possibly concatenate all the data together into a single field and then explode that out into an array in code afterwards. Simple in php.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.name, a.hg, a.mz, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('~', 'mz', b.name, a.mz+b.mz, 'charge', b.name, b.mz) SEPARATOR '~')
FROM lipids a
CROSS JOIN adduct b 
WHERE a.name='36:2'
GROUP BY a.ID, a.name, a.hg, a.mz
```

EDIT again

PHP to do the job

```
<?php

    if(preg_match('/([0-9]+):([0-9]+)/',$name))
    {
        if(!$head)
        {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.ID, a.name, a.hg, a.mz, b.name AS AdductName, a.mz+b.mz AS MzCharge, b.charge
                                FROM lipids a
                                CROSS JOIN adduct b 
                                WHERE a.name='$name'");

            $StoreArray = array();

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                $StoreArray['ID'] = $row['ID'];
                $StoreArray['name'] = $row['name'];
                $StoreArray['hg'] = $row['hg'];
                $StoreArray['mz'] = $row['mz'];
                $StoreArray['mz '.$row['AdductName']] = $row['MzCharge'];
                $StoreArray['charge '.$row['AdductName']] = $row['charge'];
            }
            print_r($StoreArray);            
        }
    }

?>
```

EDIT again

To cope with multiple lipids records with the same name

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
If (!$link) 
{
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
@mysql_select_db('testarea') or die ('Unable to select database');

$name = '36:2';


            $result = mysql_query("SELECT a.ID, a.name, a.hg, a.mz, b.name AS AdductName, a.mz+b.mz AS MzCharge, b.charge
                                FROM lipids a
                                CROSS JOIN adduct b 
                                WHERE a.name='$name'");

            $CurrId = 0;
            $StoreArray = array();

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                if ($CurrId != $row['ID'])
                {
                    $CurrId = $row['ID'];
                    $StoreArray[$CurrId] = array();
                }
                $StoreArray[$CurrId]['ID'] = $row['ID'];
                $StoreArray[$CurrId]['name'] = $row['name'];
                $StoreArray[$CurrId]['hg'] = $row['hg'];
                $StoreArray[$CurrId]['mz'] = $row['mz'];
                $StoreArray[$CurrId]['mz '.$row['AdductName']] = $row['MzCharge'];
                $StoreArray[$CurrId]['charge '.$row['AdductName']] = $row['charge'];
            }
            print_r($StoreArray);            



?>
```

Comment: Maybe my above comment can answer some of the questions?

Comment: You seem to expect an array, but MySql is set up to return a fixed number of columns whereas you want a variable number of columns depending on how many matching rows there are on adduct. You can do the join and then manually sort out the results. I will add some extra code for that.

Comment: Yeah i can see what you mean. It is because i am going to do a website, where i will get PHP to query in the database. But now i will get all in one coloum both the +h+ and -h+. And i will have more adducts. Sorry if i have my self misunderstood. But will try again. I will have a website, which uses PHP to get queries from a mysql database. Thats why i thought arrays was best. i will make an edit, with some of the code from php.

Comment: I have added some php which is untested but should do roughly what you want (and at least give you the idea).

Comment: Well it is not quite working with the indexes.. it dosent give the correct information, and the while is still only finding one solution.. but i can see where you are going... maybe i can figure it our my self, or you may come with tips :)

Comment: Minor type. Forgot to specify the alias in front of name in the WHILE clause.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with alias?

Comment: and the storearray dosent do anything, i can disable all and it will still come with same output?

Comment: Alias, as in giving the table a name for that query. Often used if you join a table against itself (so you know which copy of the table you are referring to), but also used to save typing. The above builds up an array ($StoreArray) , adding elements to that array for each row retrieved. The first 4 elements should be constant for any name from lipids and they will just be over written for each record (but over written by the same value). The other items are for each matching record on adduct and should be appended onto the end of the array.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But the while loop will still not work, only one result comes up?

Comment: Only one record should come out, but that record should contain all the details from all the relevant adduct rows.

Comment: that is true, that it does. But i have many lipids, called 36:2. So i want all lipids with the name of 36:2, and the adducts added.

Comment: Just knocked up the tables on my machine and ran the script above and the results I get are as you wanted in your original post.

Comment: Added code to cope with the added requirement of multiple lipid records with the same name.

Comment: Yes, it also do at mine. But then i have made my self misunderstood. The tables was just for an quick overview. I will have more lipids called 36:2, but with different attributes. In my website the input search will be 36:2 and then it should come up with all the answers, with the adducts added. I will edit the tables, an array of my original question, so i can make myself more clear

Comment: Does my amended suggestion work? Note that what you now have as a required output is not possible as you have multiple occurrences of the same array key.

Comment: Yes that works. Yeah i can see the problem. But how does it work? or rather why does it work?

Comment: It is using an array of arrays. Each record from lipids results in an array member, which is an array of the details for that record from lipids.